# No route to host: I can SSH to myself via the IP my router assigns me but not to myself via the IP my ISP assigns me

Tags: ssh, router, port-forwarding

I'm positive this question has been answered somewhere else but I'm not sure what to search for. (I'm trying things like "telnet ubuntu ssh daemon unable to connect".)

1. I can SSH into `10.0.0.9`
2. I can `telnet 10.0.0.9 22`
3. `sudo service ssh status` is on
4. `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` match.
5. `gufw` is off.
6. `netstat -nat | grep 22` shows `0.0.0:*` is `LISTEN` and `:::*` is `LISTEN`.
7. I believe I have my port opened correctly on the router [image: port forwarding]

So what's the missing link that I need to check that I might have done wrong? How come I can't `ssh` into `65.x.x.x` when I can `ssh` into `10.x.x.x`?

Anyone who can provide a link to an existing response or better search terms, I would much appreciate it.

---

- sample output of `tcpdump -n -i ${interface} tcp port ssh or tcpdump -n -i ${interface} host ${external_client_ip_addr}`:

`19:20:43.747445 IP 116.10.191.232.24689 > 10.0.0.9.22: Flags [.], ack 1, win 65535, length 0
19:20:43.747562 IP 116.10.191.232.24689 > 10.0.0.9.22: Flags [P.], seq 1:24, ack 1, win 65535, length 23
19:20:43.747575 IP 10.0.0.9.22 > 116.10.191.232.24689: Flags [.], ack 24, win 14600, length 0
19:20:43.759613 IP 10.0.0.9.22 > 116.10.191.232.24689: Flags [P.], seq 1:42, ack 24, win 14600, length 41
19:20:44.504741 IP 116.10.191.232.24689 > 10.0.0.9.22: Flags [P.], seq 24:832, ack 42, win 65494, length 808
19:20:44.504800 IP 10.0.0.9.22 > 116.10.191.232.24689: Flags [P.], seq 42:1026, ack 832, win 16968, length 984`

- sample output of `ssh -vvv me@67.x.x.x.x`:

`OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 67.x.x.x [67.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 67.x.x.x port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host 67.x.x.x port 22: No route to host`

Comment: Checkout NAT Hairtpin.

Comment: @Iain Something like [this](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB24639)? I can sort of conceptually understand what they're saying there, but I don't know what to type where. For example `/ip firewall nat` and `firewall nat` don't do anything useful on my system.

Comment: NAT hairpin is only relevant if he's trying to telnet 65.x.x.x from the inside network.

Comment: What about the SSH server logs or the client's output when run with `-vvv`?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu ```OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 67.x.x.x [67.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 67.x.x.x port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host 67.x.x.x port 22: No route to host```

Comment: "*ssh: connect to host 67.x.x.x port 22: No route to host*" Have you checked whether you have a route to that host?

Answer (score 4):

The screencap you've posted shows an "end port" of 23.  It's possible that this forwards a range of ports, but it's equally possible that start and end port refer to "outside port" and "inside port" respectively, in which case, you've got a problem.  Try changing the "end port" to 22.  Also, check your `/etc/hosts.{allow,deny}`.

Comment: Both ports 22 and 23 are open on that screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your ISP blocks port 22, maybe due to Heartbleed, most likely to discourage free unix shell providers.  I would suggest mapping to a different external port, see if that makes a difference.